# Can Visual Sourcesafe 2005 generate a COMPARE report for all files in a project

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-sourcesafe

I am using Sourcesafe 2005 in a 3-project solution using Visual Studio 2008.

The ONLY thing I really like about this source control tool is the COMPARE operation which shows the DIFF at a selected File level.

Is there any way to get something like this for multiple files at a time (e.g. all files in a project)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download BeyondCompare 2 or 3 or whatever is out now. It's the best comparison tool I've seen.

Comment: Thanks for this idea. I am checking into this now. Quickly, do you know if BeyondCompare can report like this and allow me to leave my Visual Studio development environment in place (with projects and files under VSS source control)?